# Opening Acrobat Files using VBA

Tags: excel, acrobat, ole, vba

I was reading from a forum thread:
https://forums.adobe.com/thread/604177 
and started experimenting with it. But I think the function didn't load at all. I wasn't sure what might the reason be behind it - I reckon it has to be simple and probably related to the library. Can someone help point out why the following code failed to compile at all (the code appeared not to have ran upon execution in immediate as none of the breakpoints triggered).

The libraries I have loaded include

- Acrobat Distiller
- Adobe Acrobat 10.0 Type Library
- Acrobat Scan 1.0 Type Library

The computer which this code is executed on have Acrobat Professional installed on it.

```
Public Function GetPDF() '(FilePath As String) As Object
    Dim origPdf As Acrobat.AcroPDDoc
    Dim path1 As String
    MsgBox ("Start")

    path1 = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
    path1 = path1 & "\31700100.pdf"

    Set origPdf = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")

    If origPdf.Open(path1) Then
        MsgBox ("weee")
    End If

    origPdf.Close
    Set origPdf = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opening documents in VBA will require you to have an Acrobat App object. The code will work once you have an app object in the function.

```
Public Function GetPDF (FilePath As String) As Object
    Dim ArcoApp As New Acrobat.AcroApp
    Dim OriPdf As New Acrobat.AcroPDDoc

    Set ArcoApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
    Set OriPdf = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")

    If OriPdf.Open(FilePath) Then
        MsgBox ("weee")
    End If

    GetPDF = OriPdf

    OriPdf.Close
    AcroApp.Close
    Set OriPdf = Nothing
    Set AcroApp =  Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a Module with this:

```
Public Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" _
(ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpOperation As String, ByVal lpFile As String, _
ByVal lpParameters As String, ByVal lpDirectory As String, ByVal nShowCmd As 
Long) As Long

Sub GetPDF()
    Dim path1 As String

    MsgBox "Start"

     path1 = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
     path1 = path1 & "\31700100.pdf"

    ShellExecute 0, "Open", path1, "", "", _        
    vbNormalNoFocus
End Sub
```

Comment: Hmm, the statement you have added showed up with a syntax error... Or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: @Isa In what line it is showing the syntax error? Im using Excel 2007 and there isn't any errors.

Comment: I am using Excel 2013. The declare function line you suggested is the highlighted as unacceptable syntax when I copied and pasted it in.

Comment: You need to re-edit the Declare Function. When you copy and paste, the "underline" marks became unreadeable. Just remove the "underline" marks and set the Declare Function in one long row. @Isa